# Intergrate pdfmake library with angularjs running with nodejs inside electron client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, electron, pdfmake

I need to intergrate pdfmake library where i installed the pdfmake using

npm install pdfmake --save

I got the module inside node_modules and i have included the library to the app.js but in runtime im getting an error with the pdfmake font js (vfs_fonts.js) seems like the app hasnt included the fonts js file.

Is there any solution on how to include the fonts js file. This library solves all my requirments on pdf making including export, preview and print features.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file you're missing is actually called `vfs_fonts.js`?

You'll need to include it in a `<script>` tag in the HTML that you're displaying inside Electron. The `vfs_fonts.js` file is also installed under `node_modules` so you can include it in your HTML like this:

```
<script src='node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
```

Comment: I very much agree with your answer but the problem is that all scripts are bundled into one JS file. (bundle.js). Is there any other alternative to do so.

Since this app is not like normal HTML, we inject JS files and angular modules separately.

Comment: and sorry about the js file name. I have accidentally put a wrong name in the post

Comment: What's creating your bundle and why? You haven't mentioned anything about that in the question?